# (iPhone) Launch an app from within another NOT working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I try to lunch an app (FirsApp) within another app (SecondApp) but its not working. This is how i did :
In my FirsApp i added this code to pList :

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>SomeKey</string>
        </array>
    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
    <string>Some identifier</string>
</dict>
```

and simply in my SecondApp i added this code in a button action :

```
 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"SomeKey://"]])
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"SomeKey://"]];
        }
        else
        {
           // Can not open app ... open app store 
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/my app page "]];
        }
```

OK , The problem is when i run **( SomeKey:// )** in safari it open my FirsApp but in my SecondApp when i want to open FirsApp it open app store **(FirsApp is already installed in my device)**
How can i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 9 Apple did some changes that broke `openUrl` feature.
If you look at your logs, you will notice there is a warning which looks like this:

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "SomeKey://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme SomeKey"

In order to fix that, you'll need to add this in your second app's `info.plist` file:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>SomeKey</string>
</array>
```

It whitelists the first app so that it can be opened safely.